# Running IIS 7 and JBoss AS 7 Simultaneously from a Windows 2008 Server

Tags: iis, web-applications, iis-7, jboss, jboss7.x

Does anybody know how to allow both IIS 7 and JBoss AS 7 to run and host applications on a Windows 2008 Server?  I have a Windows 2008 VPS that I have hosting some ASP.NET websites and apps via IIS through port 80, the default.  Now I want to host some JBoss Seam web apps (and RESTEasy web services), which presumably I will need to do on another port (eg. 8080).

I have modified the standalone.xml configuration file in JBoss AS in the standalone configuration folder so that the socket binding name "http" runs from port 8080.  However the server is not responding when I try to request my apps that are running on JBoss AS from browsers on other machines outside the server, eg:

> www.notmyrealdomain.com:8080

... does not return any response.  When I use

> localhost:8080

... to browse on the server itself, I can load web page and applications from JBoss AS just fine.  So surely there is either a Windows setting or JBoss AS setting that requires changing to get this to work.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this working:

First step - enabled incoming connections with Windows Firewall Public Profile properties!

Second step - edited the standalone/configuration/standalone.xml on my JBoss AS by replacing the default values with these values:

```
 <interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
 </interfaces>

<socket-binding-group ...>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    ...
</socket-binding-group>
```

Third step - restarted the server by running the standalone.bat file again.

Both IIS and JBoss AS successfully host apps now, although I need to specify the port address for JBoss AS apps that are deployed as I mentioned in my original question e.g. www.notmyrealdomain.com:8080/jboss-as-app/ .

Answer (score 1):

You need to make jboss as 7 instance bind against the ip that resolves to `www.notmyrealdomain.com`.

you can do that by running jboss as:

```
standalone.bat -b <EXTERNALIP>
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that this should work in theory, but when I use the above command, I can no longer call the app locally on a server web browser with "localhost" (only the assigned EXTERNALIP), and I still can't access the JBoss site externally from other machines.  Must be something else.

Comment: Is the port 8080 opened to the outside? a simple test for that would be to bring down jboss, and configure a new binding in iis to listen on port 8080 and try to connect from the outside.

Comment: It ended up being a combination of needing to alter the standalone.xml configuration file and changing Windows Firewall to allow incoming connections... I will detail below.  Thanks for your help feniix.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a subdomain like `jboss.notmyrealdomain.com` and configure IIS to redirect it to JBoss entirely. This gives benefit of using port 80 in browser.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2011/03/08/configuring-an-iis-7-front-end-for-apache-tomcat-using-appcmd-exe.aspx.

Comment: Sounded too complicated.  I am happy to just use port 8080 for JBoss AS and port 80 for IIS, for development purposes, but thanks for the potential solution.